# iOS 15: Web Audio playback stops working in Safari after locking screen for a few minutes

Tags: javascript, html, ios, mobile-safari, web-audio-api

This seems to be an issue after I upgraded my iPod Touch to iOS 15 (15.0.1).

When running the example below, it works fine on the first load, playing the sound as many times as I want. However, if I lock the screen on my iPod Touch, then return after a couple minutes, the sound no longer plays. To troubleshoot I set up a state change listener on the AudioContext instance and verified that Safari sets the state back to `running` after it was set to `interrupted` when the screen was locked. Yet, the sound does not play.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>audio-test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>

            const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
            const audioContext = new AudioContext();

            // Create AudioBuffer and fill with two seconds of white noise.
            const channels = 2;
            const frameCount = audioContext.sampleRate * 2.0;
            const audioBuffer = audioContext.createBuffer(channels, frameCount, audioContext.sampleRate);
            for (var channel = 0; channel < channels; channel++) {
                var nowBuffering = audioBuffer.getChannelData(channel);
                for (var i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
                    nowBuffering[i] = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
                }
            }

            const button = document.createElement('button');
            button.textContent = 'Play Audio';
            document.body.append(button);

            button.addEventListener('click', () => {
                const currentSourceNode = new AudioBufferSourceNode(audioContext, {
                    buffer: audioBuffer,
                });
                currentSourceNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
                currentSourceNode.start();
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Strangely, if I add an audio element to the HTML that points to some mp3 file, which isn't even referenced in the code at all, then locking the screen for a while then returning to the page no longer affects the audio playback.

Updated code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>audio-test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>

            const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
            const audioContext = new AudioContext();

            // Create AudioBuffer and fill with two seconds of white noise.
            const channels = 2;
            const frameCount = audioContext.sampleRate * 2.0;
            const audioBuffer = audioContext.createBuffer(channels, frameCount, audioContext.sampleRate);
            for (var channel = 0; channel < channels; channel++) {
                var nowBuffering = audioBuffer.getChannelData(channel);
                for (var i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
                    nowBuffering[i] = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
                }
            }

            const button = document.createElement('button');
            button.textContent = 'Play Audio';
            document.body.append(button);

            button.addEventListener('click', () => {
                const currentSourceNode = new AudioBufferSourceNode(audioContext, {
                    buffer: audioBuffer,
                });
                currentSourceNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
                currentSourceNode.start();
            });

        </script>
        <audio src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/858/outfoxing.mp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></audio>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've been banging my head against the wall for a day because of this exact problem. I can't believe this works. 

Answer (score 1):

Screen lock does not allow scripts to run on IOS.

My workaround is to run 2 audio player elements.
One audioElementWithSound and, another with an empty-10s.mp3 file.

Clicking play starts both elements.
I then have an event listner listening to 'ended' on the empty.mp3, re-starting the empty.mp3 if the withSound is not done playing yet.

It would look something like this :

```
let audioElement();
let stayAwakeAudio();

function playSound(){
    audioElement.src = "/assets/audioClip.mp3"
    audioElement.play;
    stayAwake()
}

function stayAwake() {
    console.log("I'm awake");
    stayAwakeAudio.src = "/assets/empty10sSoundFile.mp3";
    stayAwakeAudio.play();
}

stayAwakeAudio.addEventListener('ended', function () {
    if (audioElement.play) {
        console.log('Audio still playing')
        stayAwake();
    }
    else {
        console.log('No audio playing, letting screen time out');
    }
}, false);
```